# twilio sms test account giving exception

Tags: twilio-api

I am using a Twilio test account but it gives error

```
Username can not be null
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Twilio.Exceptions.AuthenticationException: Username can not be null

Source Error:


Line 24:       string TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("d89eebebe27fd448a84647e900f66275");
Line 25: 
Line 26:       TwilioClient.Init(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
Line 27: 
Line 28:       var message = MessageResource.Create(
```

My source code is below

```
    // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
    // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
    string TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AC55c243bb54e20499e8268e62383981");
    string TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("d89eebebe27fd448a647e900f66275");

    TwilioClient.Init(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

    var message = MessageResource.Create(
        body: "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?",
        from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+923212294138"),
        to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+92311344594138")
    );

    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
}
```

Comment: what prints out when you print out your TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID?

Comment: You accidentally posted your Account SID and Auth Token in this publicly available question. **[Change your Auth Token as soon as possible](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them)**, to prevent others from using the Twilio API with your credentials.
To do so, generate a secondary Auth Token, promote it to primary, and then delete the first.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you accidentally posted both your Account SID and Auth Token here in Stack Overflow. You should immediately delete/[regenerate that Auth Token](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them). The error you are facing is because you are using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` when you could actually using the values for Account SID and Auth Token themselves